# Adding and removing input fields

Tags: jquery, field, addition

I have requirement to add 4 input fields when user clicking an addAgent button. I also allow user to remove from one of those.  If user adds 4 input fields, I want to disable add button. If user removes one of those 4 input fields, then enable add button for one more to add or two more to add, depending on how many inputs user removed or added. But max only four. I would like to do this with jQuery, any help or sample I can get? Thanks!

Comment: Try researching the issue and making an attempt first. If you run into an issue at that point, you will be able to provide your code and some real context.

Comment: I have tried many samples but finally liked the below example. ONly issue with this is, I am not able to track only 4 times. http://papermashup.com/dynamically-add-form-inputs-and-submit-using-jquery/

Comment: check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/9bnMv/1/) below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working jsfiddle [[DEMO]](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/9bnMv/1/)

```
 <div id="add">Add</div>
    <div id="container"></div>

$('#add').bind('click', function() {
    if($('#container').find('input').length < 4) {
        $('#container').append('<div><input type="text"><span class="remove">remove</span></div>');
    }
})

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    if($('#container').find('input').length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
})
```

Comment: I clicked the tick mark. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: That's all. If you want to vote then you can click up icon.

Comment: will there be any isse if I have other input fileds as it is finiding "input" .?if($('#container').find('input').length > 0)

Comment: No. You can specify some class on these input which you want to remove then you can find by that class instead of input.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?
You could create four inputs like this:

```
 <div class='control'>
        <input type='text' value='' />
        <a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div class='control'>
        <input type='text' value='' />
        <a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div class='control'>
        <input type='text' value='' />
        <a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>
    </div><div class='control'>
        <input type='text' value='' />
        <a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>
    </div>
```

Then you could write jquery to hide them initially and show them on click of a button.

Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kSH7M/1

Comment: Awesome!!!! Thank you verymuch. Is there anyway I cann add one input for each click of a button instead of adding 4 at a time?

Comment: I have received answer from Deepa and I have accepted. But Thank you verymuch for your help!